how to find expression of $a\text{ mod } n$ using polynomial of $e^{\frac{2a\pi i}{n}}$?
I tried to find a polynomial for $a\text{ mod } n$ (for $a,n\in N$)  by using powers of $\exp\left(\frac{2a\pi i}{n}\right)$
which mean find the coefficients $f(n,k)$ in
$$ a\text{ mod } n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(n,k)\exp\left(\frac{2ak\pi i}{n}\right)$$
where for $n=1$ we have $a\text{ mod } 1=0$ So $f(1,0)=0$
and for $n=2$ I got
$$a\text{ mod } 2=\frac{1}{2}\exp\left(\frac{2a(0)\pi i}{2}\right)-\frac{1}{2} \exp\left(\frac{2a(1)\pi i}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{(-1)^a}{2}$$
which mean $f(2,0)=\frac{1}{2} ,f(2,1)=\frac{-1}{2}$
and for $n=4$ we can find it from formula of $a\text{ mod } 2$ which is
$$ a\text{ mod } 4=\frac{1}{2} \left(3+i^n(-1+i)-i^{2n}-i^{3n}(1+i) \right)$$
which mean
$$ f(4,0)=\frac{3}{2} , f(4,1)=\frac{-1+i}{2} , f(4,2)=\frac{-1}{2} , f(4,3)=\frac{-1-i}{2}$$
but for $n=3$ I didn't got it but I found in OEIS A010872 a formula from Guenther Schrack posted in 2019/09/23
$$a\text{ mod } 3=\frac{1}{3} \left(r^n (r-1)-r^{2n}(r+2)+3 \right) $$
where $r=\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{3}\right)$ So
$$ f(3,0)=\frac{r-1}{3} , f(3,1)=-\frac{r+2}{3} , f(3,2)=1$$
and by using $a\text{ mod } 2$ and $a\text{ mod } 4$ I got a long formula for $a\text{ mod } 8$
So we can get all cases $n=6,8,12,16,18,...,2^a\times 3^b$ from the cases $n=2,3$
now can we get a formula for $a\text{ mod } n$ ?
which mean general formula or a recurrence relation for $f(n,k)$
and can we get a formula for $f(nm,k)$ if we know values of $f(n,k) , f(m,k)$ ?
also what is values of $f(5,k)$ ? I think it can be found here but I didn't get it.

This can be done using the discrete Fourier transform: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform

The main thing is that, if $p$ is prime, and $\zeta=e^{2\pi i/p}$, then $1+\zeta^k+\zeta^{2k}+\dotsb+\zeta^{(p-1)k}$ is $p$ if $k\equiv0\bmod p$ and zero otherwise.

@QiaochuYuan how can we use it ? can you explain please ?

The discrete Fourier transform has an inverse. In other words, if
$$g(a)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(k)e^{2\pi i ka/n},$$
then
$$f(k)=\frac1n\left(\sum_{a=0}^{n-1}g(a)e^{-2\pi ika/n}\right).$$

from comments I learnt about the Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) which give us
$$g(n,a)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(n,k) \exp\left(\frac{2ak \pi i}{n} \right) \leftrightarrow f(n,k)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{p=0}^{n-1} g(n,p)\exp\left(-\frac{2pk \pi i}{n} \right) $$
now we have
$$a \text{ mod }n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(n,k) \exp\left(\frac{2ak \pi i}{n} \right) $$
So
$$f(n,k)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{p=0}^{n-1} (p\text{ mod }n)\exp\left(-\frac{2pk \pi i}{n} \right) $$
but $p\text{ mod }n=p \space \space \forall \space p\in\{0,1,2,...,n-1\}$
So we get
$$f(n,k)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{p=0}^{n-1} p\exp\left(-\frac{2pk \pi i}{n} \right) $$
and to simplify it from derivation the summation of geometric series we have
$$ \sum_{p=0}^{n-1} p x^p=\frac{(n-1)x^{n+1}-nx^n+x}{(x-1)^2} , x\ne 1$$
So for $f(n,k) , k\ne0 $ put $x=\exp\left(-\frac{2k \pi i}{n} \right)\to x^n=1$ then
$$f(n,k)=\frac{1}{n}\frac{(n-1)\exp\left(-\frac{2k \pi i}{n} \right)-n+\exp\left(-\frac{2k \pi i}{n} \right)}{(\exp\left(-\frac{2k \pi i}{n} \right)-1)^2}=\frac{1}{\exp\left(-\frac{2k \pi i}{n} \right)-1} $$
So
$$ f(n,k)=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2} \cot \left(\frac{k}{n}\pi \right), k\ne0 \tag{1}$$
now for $k=0$ we have
$$f(n,0)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{p=0}^{n-1} p=\frac{n-1}{2} \tag{2}$$
So we can see for example from (1) $f(5,0)=2$ and from (2)
$$ f(5,1)=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2} \cot \left(\frac{\pi}{5} \right) \space \space \space, f(5,2)=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2} \cot \left(\frac{2\pi}{5} \right) $$
$$ f(5,3)=-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2} \cot \left(\frac{2\pi}{5} \right) \space \space \space , f(5,4)=-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2} \cot \left(\frac{\pi}{5} \right) $$
and about finding $f(nm,k)$ in terms of $f(n,k) , f(m,k)$ we need to find $\cot \left(\frac{k}{nm}\pi \right)$ in terms of $\cot \left(\frac{k}{n}\pi \right) , \cot \left(\frac{k}{m}\pi \right)$
